# error deploying to Google Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm trying to deploy my java based appengine app through the eclipse plugin. I get an error at the very end of the process whichI pasted below. Any ideas what this could mean?

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException: Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: http://appengine.google.com/api/queue/update?app_id=ipoobeta&version=v1-6&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:62)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:271)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error posting to URL: http://appengine.google.com/api/queue/update?app_id=ipoobeta&version=v1-6&
500 Internal Server Error

Server Error (500)
A server error has occurred.

at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ServerConnection.send(ServerConnection.java:143)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.ServerConnection.post(ServerConnection.java:81)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:522)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.updateQueue(AppVersionUpload.java:255)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:134)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:56)
... 4 more
```

Comment: A quick update: Even though eclipse is reporting an error the application sill deploys. HOWEVER, my task queues are not deployed as specified in my queue.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was written there have been many enhancements to the serving infrastructure of Google App Engine. Be sure you are using the High Replication Datastore (HRD). It is extremely unlikely that you will encounter this type of error and if you do it will be transient.